# Preserving line breaks when parsing with Scrapy in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written a Scrapy spider that extracts text from a page. The spider parses and outputs correctly on many of the pages, but is thrown off by a few. I'm trying to maintain line breaks and formatting in the document. Pages such as http://www.state.gov/r/pa/prs/dpb/2011/04/160298.htm are formatted properly like such:

> April 7, 2011
>
> Mark C. Toner
>
> 2:03 p.m. EDT
>
> MR. TONER: Good afternoon, everyone. A couple of things at the top,
>   and then I‚Äôll take your questions. We condemn the attack on innocent
>   civilians in southern Israel in the strongest possible terms, as well
>   as ongoing rocket fire from Gaza. As we have reiterated many times,
>   there‚Äôs no justification for the targeting of innocent civilians,
>   and those responsible for these terrorist acts should be held
>   accountable. We are particularly concerned about reports that indicate
>   the use of an advanced anti-tank weapon in an attack against civilians
>   and reiterate that all countries have obligations under relevant
>   United Nations Security Council resolutions to prevent illicit
>   trafficking in arms and ammunition. Also just a brief statement --
>
> QUESTION: Can we stay on that just for one second?
>
> MR. TONER: Yeah. Go ahead, Matt.
>
> QUESTION: Apparently, the target of that was a school bus. Does that
>   add to your outrage?
>
> MR. TONER: Well, any attack on innocent civilians is abhorrent, but
>   certainly the nature of the attack is particularly so.

While pages like http://www.state.gov/r/pa/prs/dpb/2009/04/121223.htm have output like this with no line breaks:

> April 2, 2009
>
> Robert Wood
>
> 11:53 a.m. EDTMR. WOOD: Good morning, everyone. I think it‚Äôs just
>   about still morning. Welcome to the briefing. I don‚Äôt have anything,
>   so ‚Äì sir.QUESTION: The North Koreans have moved fueling tankers, or
>   whatever, close to the site. They may or may not be fueling this
>   missile. What words of wisdom do you have for the North Koreans at
>   this moment?MR. WOOD: Well, Matt, I‚Äôm not going to comment on, you
>   know, intelligence matters. But let me just say again, we call on the
>   North to desist from launching any type of missile. It would be
>   counterproductive. It‚Äôs provocative. It further inflames tensions in
>   the region. We want to see the North get back to the Six-Party
>   framework and focus on denuclearization.Yes.QUESTION: Japan has also
>   said they‚Äôre going to call for an emergency meeting in the Security
>   Council, you know, should this launch go ahead. Is this something that
>   you would also be looking for?MR. WOOD: Well, let‚Äôs see if this test
>   happens. We certainly hope it doesn‚Äôt. Again, calling on the North
>   not to do it. But certainly, we will ‚Äì if that test does go forward,
>   we will be having discussions with our allies.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s' % response.url) 

    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    speaker = hxs.select("//span[contains(@class, 'official_s_name')]") #gets the speaker
    speaker = speaker.select('string()').extract()[0] #extracts speaker text
    date = hxs.select('//*[@id="date_long"]') #gets the date
    date = date.select('string()').extract()[0] #extracts the date
    content = hxs.select('//*[@id="centerblock"]') #gets the content
    content = content.select('string()').extract()[0] #extracts the content

    texts = "%s\n\n%s\n\n%s" % (date, speaker, content) #puts everything together in a string

    filename = ("/path/StateDailyBriefing-" + '%s' ".txt") % (date) #creates a file using the date

    #opens the file defined above and writes 'texts' using utf-8
    with codecs.open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output:
        output.write(texts)
```

I think they problem lies in the formatting of the HTML of the page. On the pages that output the text incorrectly, the paragraphs are separated by `<br> <p></p>`, while on the pages that output correctly the paragraphs are contained within `<p align="left" dir="ltr">`. So, while I've identified this, I'm not sure how to make everything output consistently in the correct form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that when you getting `text()` or `string()`, `<br>` tags are not converted to newline.

Workaround - replace `<br>` tags before doing XPath requests. Code:

```
response = response.replace(body=response.body.replace('<br />', '\n')) 
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
```

And let me give some advice, if you know, that there is only one node, you can use `text()` instead `string()`:

```
date = hxs.select('//*[@id="date_long"]/text()').extract()[0]
```

Comment: I would suggest replacing the plain string by a regex to be less restrictive : `response = response.replace( body=re.sub(r"<br\s*[\/]?>", "\n", response.body) ) `

Answer (score 3):

Try this xpath:

```
//*[@id="centerblock"]//text()
```

Comment: You will not be able to just `''.join(content)` because text doesn't contain newlines, and `'\n'.join(content)` will split not only paragraphs, but `<b>...</b>` too.

Comment: This works, but because of the requirement to join the list @reclosedev has a cleaner and simpler method. Thank you, though.