# Can't make Scrapy / Xpath take note of double <br>

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to use scrapy to crawl some poems and i have this text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br>  
consectetuer adipiscing elit.<br> 
<br> 
Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.<br> 
Aenean massa
```

And i select it's xpath with scrapy like this:

```
In [1]: sel.xpath('//div[@class="box"]/text()').extract()
Out[1]:
[u'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,',
 u'consectetuer adipiscing elit.',
 u'Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.',
 u'Aenean massa',]
```

How can i make it so it doesn't ignore the extra br ?

Comment: What about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748053/preserving-line-breaks-when-parsing-with-scrapy-in-python

Comment: Indeed `response = response.replace(body=response.body.replace('<br />', '\n'))`  works perfect, sorry, somehow i didn't find this question.

Comment: `response = response.replace( body=re.sub(r"<br\s*[\/]?>", "\n", response.body) )` is less restrictive as it matches `<br>` and `<br />` tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The XPath query *forces* Scrapy not to return `<br>` tags

Scrapy ignores the `<br>` tags, because you told it to do so. You XPath query

```
//div[@class="box"]/text()
```

selects all direct text node children of `//div[@class="box"]`, and only selects those. Any other node types are simply ignored, among those the `<br>` tags.

#### Extending the Search to `<br>` tags

If you also want the `<br>` tokens to be returned, select both text nodes and `<br>` tokens:

```
(//div[@class="box"]/text() | //div[@class="box"]/br)
```

Now, loop over all results. If you come over a text node, return its contents, for (`<br>`) tags return newlines.

Comment: Indeed from XPath point this seems the correct solution, would like to point that with scrapy the above comment also work. Thank you for such a complete answer.