# Scrape data from div as shown on the page

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape data from this URL https://eksisozluk.com/mortingen-sitraze--1277239, I want to scrape the title and then all the comments beneath the title. If you open the website you will see that the first comment under the title is **(bkz: mortingen)**. The problem is that **(bkz** is in a div and inside the div **mortingen** is inside an anchor link, so it makes it difficult to scrape the data as shown on the webste. Can anyone help me with a CSS Selector or Xpath that can scrape all comments as shown.
My code is written below but it gives me **(bkz:** in one column then **akhisar** and then **)** in three seperate columns instead of one

```
def parse(self, response):
    data={}
    #count=0
    title = response.css('[itemprop="name"]::text').get()
    #data["Title"] = title
    count=0
    data["title"] = title
    count=0
    for content in response.css('li .content ::text'):
        text = content.get()
        text=text.strip()
        content = "content" +str(count)
        data[content] = text
        count=count+1
    yield data
```

Comment: get it in two steps - first `bkz:`, next `mortingen` and later join it into one string.

Comment: we can't run code so we can't see that it is in separated columns. Why don't use get it in one list and later join all in one list and after then put it in one column

Comment: or maybe you should first get all `.content` without `::text` and use `for`-loop to work withe every `.content` separatelly and get all `::text` only in selected `.content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first get all `.content` without `::text` and use `for`-loop to work with every `.content` separatelly. And for every `.content` you should run `::text` to get all text only in this content, put on list and later join it into single string

```py
       for count, content in enumerate(response.css('li .content')):
            text = []

            # get all `::text` in current `.content`
            for item in content.css('::text'):
                item = item.get()#.strip()
                # put on list
                text.append(item)

            # join all items in single string
            text = "".join(text)
            text = text.strip()

            print(count, '|', text)
            data[f"content {count}"] = text
```

---

Minimal working code.

You can put all code in one file and run `python script.py` without creating project in `scrapy`.

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    start_urls = ['https://eksisozluk.com/mortingen-sitraze--1277239']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        data = {}  # PEP8: spaces around `=`

        title = response.css('[itemprop="name"]::text').get()
        data["title"] = title

        for count, content in enumerate(response.css('li .content')):
            text = []

            for item in content.css('::text'):
                item = item.get()#.strip()
                text.append(item)

            text = "".join(text)
            text = text.strip()

            print(count, '|', text)
            data[f"content {count}"] = text

        yield data
    
# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEEDS': {'output.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},  # new in 2.1
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Little shorter with `getall()`

```py
        for count, content in enumerate(response.css('li .content')):

            text = content.css('::text').getall()

            text = "".join(text)
            text = text.strip()

            print(count, '|', text)
            data[f"content {count}"] = text
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, it worked like a charm

Comment: Hey, so the code you mentioned worked quite well, but I had a question?
 When there is a paragraph on the page, it has <br> so paragraphs have spaces between lines. How can I preserve them when I am scraping? At the moment the line breaks are ignored and the paragraphs are joined

Comment: you will have to replace `<br>`  with `'\n"` before scraping - [Preserving line breaks when parsing with Scrapy in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748053/preserving-line-breaks-when-parsing-with-scrapy-in-python)